# Split data in Chr(10) into new line

Tags: vba, excel

I want to break selection (B3, B4..etc) into new row.. Please help me. 
for a example= If I select B3 cell, I wanna add more 3 Rows and 2nd to 4th line should be move down. Always not same line break in each cell.

[image: Please see attached picture]

Answer (score 3):

Splitting the cell into an array of strings is simple with [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) using the [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function) function.

If cell `A1` contains a string with `Chr(10)`'s (`LF`/Linefeed characters) then you could split it into an array with VBA like this:

```
Dim myArr() as String
myArr = Split(Range("A1"), Chr(10))
```

...then you could dump it into a range of cells *horizontally* (with the help of [`UBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ubound-function)) like this:

```
Dim startColumn As Integer
startColumn = 2
Range(Cells(1, startColumn), Cells(1, startColumn + UBound(myArr))) = myArr()
```

...or you could dump it into a range of cells *vertically* like this:

```
Dim startRow As Integer, x As Integer
startRow = 2

For x = 0 To UBound(myArr)
    Range("A" & x + startRow) = myArr(x)
Next x
```

You haven't shared the code you've tried so far, but I trust you'll should be able to handle the "inserting rows" part with [*`Range.Insert`*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-insert-method-excel), or a quick Google Search (if you don't already know how).

Answer (score 1):

use split function and variant array.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vSplit
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
    vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        vSplit = Split(vDB(i, 2), Chr(10))
        For j = 0 To UBound(vSplit)
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 3, 1 To n)
            If j = 0 Then
                vR(1, n) = vDB(i, 1)
                vR(3, n) = vDB(i, 3)
            End If
            vR(2, n) = vSplit(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(n, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```